# I have used "position" property with value "sticky" but it is'nt working so

Tags: html, css, position, sticky

I was trying to give a look of "vertical navigation bar" which would get fixed to the page once topmost option of bar touches 0px from top.
**I used "lorem10000" in "html" to get scroller with "float:right;" and "width:75%;".**
But it is not getting fixed after scrolling.

here is HTML code...

```
<div >
    <div class="box" id="box1">Childhood</div>
    <div class="box" id="box2">Early life</div>
    <div class="box" id="box3"> Career </div>
     
   </div>
```

here is CSS...

```
   #box1{
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    width: 20%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    
  }
  #box2{
      position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    width: 20%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    
  }
  #box3{
      position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 50px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    width: 20%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hei, instead of making all 3 elements sticky why don't you try wrapping them into a container? I made some code that would make you understand better what I mean (you can also try it on JSFiddle

At first, let's add a new class called `container` to the bigger div

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class="box" id="box1">Childhood</div>
    <div class="box" id="box2">Early life</div>
    <div class="box" id="box3"> Career </div>     
</div>
```

then, let's apply some style to it, like so

```
.container{
   position: -webkit-sticky;
   position: sticky;
   top: 0;
}
```

at last, let's remove the unnecessary code from those 3 specific elements

(I removed `position: -webkit-sticky; position: sticky;`  from each mini container)

```
#box1{
    top: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    width: 20%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;   
}
  
#box2{
    top: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    width: 20%;
    margin-bottom: 5px; 
}

#box3{
    top: 50px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    width: 20%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

You can try a demo here [working sticky menu](https://jsfiddle.net/kgeht5dq/4/)

Comment: First of all, a **Great Thanks** for reply!!!  But u didn't caught my point, problem arises when we add `p{
  float:right;
  width:70%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}` this **CSS** for **p** element.  After adding this **CSS** "position" **sticky** does'nt  works. Actually I am finding **"float"** more confusing, so, please tell how "float" is working here.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. **float** property says where the element should "float", where it should stand. So if you say `float: right;`, the elements float right. This property often has issues with positioning, and floats overwrite any positioning put in place. To avoid this, you can use the `left` or `right` property, in the CSS, instead of the float
The code will change from `float: right;` to `left: 30%` or something like this. Hope this explains a little

Comment: Try looking around and also look at this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31767497/fixed-position-and-float-not-working-correctly)